# How can I authenticate user with Email and password using React and Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am invoking a method through on Click where this code is placed

```
handleEmail =()=>{
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword('abc@abc.com', '123').catch(function(error) {
  // Handle Errors here.
  var errorCode = error.code;
  var errorMessage = error.message;
  });
}
```

Comment: There are no errors on the console as well.The method seems to work.

Comment: are you printing errors? because you're catching errors that occur in the auth promise.

Comment: For one thing, with that code you're _creating a new user_ not authenticating an existing one. For another, the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` function returns a promise, so you would need a `then()` chain following it to do anything with the resulting success.

Comment: The issue has been solved.The problem was i was using the button (that fired the above method) within `<form><./form>` tags.Whereas, when i used   it in `<div></div>` tags it worked like a charm!.Thanks.